# Create form for Uploadable Doctrine Extension

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-uploadable

I'd like to use Uploadable to save some images (i.e. profile picture for users). I'm using many other Doctrine Extensions already (softdeletable, timestampable, blameable, etc.) so I thought it would be nice to use this one as well.

However, I don't know how to set up my Forms. The StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle [documentation](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) gives this example:

```
$document = new Document();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($document)
    ->add('name')
    ->add('myFile')
    ->getForm()
;

//(...)

$uploadableManager->markEntityToUpload($document, $document->getMyFile());
```

In this example, is `name` the name of the Document or the name of the file?

Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions's [documentation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/uploadable.md) adds a `path`, `name`, `mimeType` and `size` to an entity, to there is no `myFile` attribute.

Can anybody explain how to set up a Form for a Uploadable Doctrine entity? I couldn't find any documentation or good example that helped me further.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493126/file-uploads-with-doctrine

Comment: Thanks, but that those links don't explain how to configure a FormType.

Comment: The configuration goes with the entity. To the FormType you should use something like 
->add('picture')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Entity

Like you've discovered, the [documentation of DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/uploadable.md) itself sheds some light on how to configure the Uploadable extension to use your entity.

Mainly by adding the `@Gedmo\Uploadable` annotation to your entity and `@Gedmo\UploadableFilePath` to the property that will contain the file path (`$filePath` for example).

#### Form

With the `->add()` method of the form-builder you add fields to the form. The first parameter specifies the property-name of the corresponding entity. So `->add('myFile')` would add a field for the property `$myFile`.

What you need to do is add a (file) field to the form for the property that will contain the file path (`$filePath` for example), and mark that property:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity)
    ->add('filePath');

$uploadableManager->markEntityToUpload($entity, $entity->getFilePath());
```

In other words: `myFile` in your example should be replaced with `filePath` in my example, and whatever the actual property is in your real code.